# Iframe document undefined if not hovered over

Tags: html

Weirdly, I'm not being able to access my iframe document data.

```
document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document.getElementById('testme').click()
```

I'm trying to get the iframe content; and press the ID testme.

This has never happened to me, it also appears that it automatically stops finding my iframe, say when I reload the page; and search for my iframe document doing following:

```
document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow
```

It says undefined.

But when I go back and hover through the HTML elements it seems to be working again...

Here's my full code:

```
<html>
<iframe  id = "iframe" src="{{movie_url}}" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="640" height="360" allowfullscreen="true" name="iframe" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
<script>
    var frame_2 = document.getElementById("iframe").contentWindow.document.getElementById('tetme').click()

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until your iframe load.

If you use jQuery, for ex.

```
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    var iframe = $("#iframe").contents();
    iframe.find("#testme").click(function() {
      //code
    })
  }, 1000);
```

You can also wait for window load.